# Double hash usage

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c-preprocessor

In C99 6.10.3.3.(2) (with my highlight)

> If, in the replacement list of a function-like macro, a parameter is immediately preceded
> or followed by a ## preprocessing token, the parameter is replaced by the corresponding
> argument’s preprocessing token sequence; however, **if an argument consists of no
> preprocessing tokens, the parameter is replaced by a placemarker preprocessing token
> instead.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define hash_hash(a, b) a ## b
#define mkstr(a) # a
#define in_between(a) mkstr(a)

void main(void)
{
    char p[] = in_between(a hash_hash(,) b);
    printf("%s", p);
}
```

Output:

```
a  b
```

I described the highlighted phrase by `hash_hash(,)` and result seemed correct as the standard's representation.

But I wonder if comma `,` is omitted, like `hash_hash()`, then does this differ from standard's explanation (undefined behavior)? And is the `placemaker` the same as white-space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I wonder if comma , is omitted, like hash_hash(), then does this differ from standard's explanation (undefined behavior)?

I think the relevant part is C11 6.10.3/4 emphasis mine:

> **Constraints**
>
> If the identifier-list in the macro definition does not end with an ellipsis, the number of arguments (**including those arguments consisting of no preprocessing tokens**) in an invocation of a function-like macro shall equal the number of parameters in the macro definition.

The comma would give a valid identifier list with no pre-proc tokens, but without it the identifier list doesn't match the macro's number of parameters. So  `hash_hash()` is a constraint violation and you should get a diagnostic message.

Answer (score 1):

*if comma `,` is omitted, like `hash_hash()`, then does this differ from standard's explanation (undefined behavior)? And is the placemaker the same as white-space?*

Yes,  If a macro is defined with arguments, the arguments *must* be separated with a comma delimiter. Attempts to define a multiple argument macro otherwise would violate the rules of the standard, and it would not compile:

> Function-like macros can take arguments, just like true functions. To
> define a macro that uses arguments, you insert parameters between the
> pair of parentheses in the macro definition that make the macro
> function-like. The parameters must be valid C identifiers,
> ***separated by commas*** and optionally whitespace.

Furthermore,

- Because this requirement is [well defined](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macro-Arguments.html), it would not be an example of undefined behavior.
- In this phrase of the reference paragraph ***and*** *optionally whitespace*, the *and* indicates that white space can be used along with a delimiter, but by itself is not sufficient as a delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

> But I wonder if comma `,` is omitted, like `hash_hash()`, then does this differ from standard's explanation(undefined behavior)?

The comma in this case is part of the syntax of function-like macro invocation.  It separates parameters in the macro's parameter list.  Invocations of a function-like macro must provide a value for each of that macro's named parameters, and with `hash_hash()` (without the comma) you would not be doing so.  This would be a violation of a language constraint, so not only would the resulting behavior be undefined, but a conforming C implementation is obligated to emit a diagnostic when it encounters such a violation.

> And is the `placemaker` the same as white-space?

No.  You can conceptualize placemarkers as a zero-length preprocessing tokens.  Such a thing is not directly representable in source code.  It is neither whitespace nor absence of preprocessing tokens.  "Placemarker" is a pretty good description of its nature and role.